# MHA vs Orchestrator

Tags: mysql, high-availability, gtid, proxysql, mysql-mha

Im going to setup an HA solution. Im planning to use Orchestrator. But seems MHA is also doing well.

If anyone already used/using any one these solutions, please suggest me to choose a right one with the following requirements.

1. Fastest failover
2. Multiple slaves are there.
3. Make old master as read only it comes back.
4. Im using ProxySQL on top it. Will it automatically detect the new master?
5. GTID is enabled.

Comment: For "fastest", I think _you_ will have to benchmark it in _your_ environment.